# Latest release of koma-script: compilation hangs at tocbasic

Tags: koma-script, tocbasic

I had been using a modified version of this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/my-resume/qxsxdtmknkfr for my resume without problems (class file at https://github.com/GiantMolecularCloud/my-resume). I recently updated my distribution files, and now the compilation hangs at tocbasic (I just tried with the template instead of my own resume, same result).

Extracting to the working directory a few files from the [previous version of koma-script](https://sourceforge.net/settings/mirror_choices?projectname=koma-script&filename=KOMA-Script/koma-script-3546.zip&selected=phoenixnap), version 3546, solved the problem.

So I do have a workaround (a more permanent one would be to replace the distribution files by the earlier version, to avoid having to extract these files to whichever folder I am using for compiling the current file). Nevertheless, I would be interested in knowing if there is maybe just a small change that could be done to the current version of the file(s) to make it work properly...

---

example

```
\documentclass[%singlesided,
               doublesided,
               paper=a4,
               fontsize=10pt
              ]{my-resume-test}


\stop
```

where `my-resume-test.cls` is

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions*



\LoadClass{scrartcl}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, this is fixed in the Patch Level 1 LaTeX release which went to CTAN yesterday, meanwhile if you change the resume class file to add two `\expandafter` so it looks like `\DeclareOption*{\expandafter\PassOptionsToClass\expandafter{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}`  then it will work with or without the latex format patch update.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/580

Comment: Your original example should work with a texlive 2021 updated today (2021-06-16)

Comment: Thank you very much! Somehow I did a check for package updates with the TeXLive manager and it does not show anything, maybe the 2021-06-16 update has not replicated yet to my closest server. I see 58585 (3.33) as my current version of koma-script. So I will test in the next few days the updated package if it shows up, or your fix if it does not.